# Google Transliterate value to place in another div

Tags: javascript

In the example startArea value is used to convert text from one language to another, and places there itself.

How come i place that converted text into finalId element.

I had searched in the translate API, I didnt found any answer. is there any API related Support.

Here is the script i used

```
 <textarea id="startArea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>

 <textarea id="finalId" readonly="readonly" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>



// Load the Google Transliterate API
    google.load("elements", "1", {
          packages: "transliteration"
        });

    function onLoad() {
      var options = {
          sourceLanguage:
              google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
          destinationLanguage:
              [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.TELUGU],
          shortcutKey: 'alt+t',
          transliterationEnabled: true
      };

      // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
      // options.
        var control =
          new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'startArea'.

        control.makeTransliteratable(['startArea']);

    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Google Transliterate API](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) is Deprecated, and I think you're getting a Javascript error when loading the page that is rendering useless the logic.

In any case, you could follow [this section](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started#transliterateLowLevel) to load the "transliterate" library and use the function there call to make the transliteration directly whenever you want to do it. The result will be the argument of the callback function.